# How to check if a ParseRelation is null prior fetching it

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, relational-database

I am trying to see if an objects relation  is null, if not then continue on. It keeps crashing on this line throwing a NullPointerException. How would I resolve this? I'm trying to see if this is null or not to begin with, but it just crashes saying NullPointerException?

```
    if (currentObject.getRelation("interested") != null)
```

where currentObject is the ParseObject.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Fixed the issue, I'm a moron and didn't realize the currentObject wasn't being set yet as it was being called inside a block.

Comment: Yeah, that's about the only way that line could throw an NPE.